# Add multiply shapefiles in one figure (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have 4 shape file. I know how to read  them  using this code:

```
% first shape file is for whole country
Country = 'country.shp'
S_country = shaperead (country);
M_country = mapshow (S_country); % >>>> I want to be in a white with black border <<<< can you please tell me how to?

% Second shape file for a sea in the north
north_sea = 'caspian sea.shp'
S_north_sea = shaperead (north_sea);
M_north_sea = mapshow (S_north_sea ); % I want to be in blue with no border

% Third shape file for a gulf in the south
Sout_gulf = 'persiangulf.shp'
S_Sout_gulf = shaperead (Sout_gulf);
M_Sout_gulf = mapshow (S_Sout_gulf); % I want to be in blue with no border

% Fourth Shape file for a sea in the south
south_sea = 'oman sea.shp'
S_south_sea = shaperead (south_sea);
M_south_sea = mapshow (S_south_sea); % I want to be in blue with no border
```

But I don't know how to have all of them in the one figure to have a nicely figure of a country with sea in north and south with colors that I mentioed in the comments of code.
I attach all 4 shape file [here in my google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J2Z5m-Y4SqCt4nDDbO4ObpMMascFznhK). 
Thank you.

**Update**

Thanks to your guidance in a comment below, I used this:
But still, I can't have all the figures in one

```
country = 'country.shp'
S_country = shaperead (country);
north_sea = 'caspian sea.shp'
S_north_sea = shaperead (north_sea);
figure
mapshow (S_country); 
hold on
mapshow (S_north_sea );
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/mapshow.html#namevaluepairarguments) should explain how to do this. To plot multiple things to the same figure, use `hold on` after your first draw command, subsequent ones will add  to the figure instead of overwrite what was there.

Comment: Dear @CrisLuengo thanks to your guidance I updated my question.